# News API that would allow search by source and Date

Tags: api, keyword, feed, google-news

I am looking for a news API that allows me to map specific keywords and sources to the number of articles published in a specific time frame.

For example a user will input

```
{keyword1, source1, beginDate, endDate}
```

and the output will be

```
There are xx articles.
Display the titles and url of articles
```

The time frame can be even a year, like from Jan 1st 2011 to Jan 1st 2012.
Google news seemed promising but the API has been deprecated and you can only search within two months in the current year. 
I looked at New York Times API and it is exactly what I am looking for but for multiple sources not just NYT.
Feedzilla does not provide search by source or time frame functionality plus it only allows retrieving 100 articles.

I have been looking around the web and couldn't find anything useful, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could take the FREE web services route?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what would be available publicly to host this for you but you could always build your RSS parsing tool, store in a local database and then use SQL or the like to read from the database.  Shoot me an email if you need some help, I was thinking of making a project like this myself.

Comment: You could also try the Feedly api: https://developer.feedly.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [News is free](http://www.newsisfree.com/webservice.php) and its [API](http://www.newsisfree.com/apiservice.php)?

I haven't tried this one, but it seems to have a [`directSearch` operation](http://www.newsisfree.com/apiservice.php?f=directSearch#doc), which seems to allow for filtering on dates (and tags)...

> ```
> > directSearch(login, password, search, params)
>
> This method searches the news, depending on given parameters. The analog of newsisfree advanced search.
> application_key (string) - application key;
> login (string) - user login;
> password (string) - user password;
> search (string) - search string;
> params (string) - hash array of additional search parameters (very important to use 'params' array values order as shown below);
> as_language - language code (e.g. en,fr,it)
> numitems - number of items to search (max 100)
> source_id - source id
> as_sourcename - source name
> as_category - category id
> as_author - author name
> as_topics - topics
> as_date_from - from date (YYYY/MM/DD)
> as_date_to - to date (YYYY/MM/DD)
> as_pop_from - from popularity (0
> as_exact - exact match
> as_synonym - use synonyms
> as_relevance - by relevance
> as_intitle - only in titles
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to www.feedzilla.com,
this gives you news feeds with the category filter.